# Vertically concat MySQL tables, inserting NULLs

Tags: mysql

I have a table `mmm` with `main_id`s, and 2 tables (`ppp` and `ccc`) with `main_id`s and sub-IDs, like this

### Table Structure

```
Table `mmm`      Table `ppp`               Table `ccc`
+---------+      +---------+--------+      +---------+--------+
| main_id |      | main_id | ppp_id |      | main_id | ccc_id |
+---------+      +---------+--------+      +---------+--------+
|       1 |      |       1 |      1 |      |       3 |      1 |
|       2 |      |       2 |      2 |      |       4 |      2 |
|       3 |      +---------+--------+      +---------+--------+
|       4 |
+---------+
```

The `ccc`s and the `ppp`s get their `main_id`s from the pool of `main_id`s in `mmm`.

### Commands to construct

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
USE test;
CREATE TABLE mmm (main_id INT, PRIMARY KEY (main_id));
CREATE TABLE ppp (main_id INT, ppp_id INT, FOREIGN KEY (main_id) REFERENCES mmm (main_id));
CREATE TABLE ccc (main_id INT, ccc_id INT, FOREIGN KEY (main_id) REFERENCES mmm (main_id));
INSERT INTO mmm VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);
INSERT INTO ppp VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2);
INSERT INTO ccc VALUES (3, 1), (4, 2);
```

I want to write a query that produces this result:

### Desired Output

```
+---------+--------+--------+
| main_id | ppp_id | ccc_id |
+---------+--------+--------+
|       1 |      1 |  NULL  |
|       2 |      2 |  NULL  |
|       3 |  NULL  |      1 |
|       4 |  NULL  |      2 |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

So I want to stack `ppp` and `ccc` on top of each other, filling in `NULL` values where there isn't an entry in the other table. I have been experimenting with joins and haven't been able to produce this result. The closest I came was

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mmm,
    ppp,
    ccc
WHERE
    mmm.main_id = ppp.main_id OR
    mmm.main_id = ccc.main_id
GROUP BY
    mmm.main_id
;
```

but that doesn't quite do it properly because there are still non-NULL values in the table with non-matching `main_id`s.

Comment: And please note that we stopped using this syntax circa 25 years ago. Come. Join us.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you for the helpful link. I have now included commands for construction of the sample database. And can you clarify what you mean by "this syntax?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `left join`s:

```
select main_id, p.ppp_id, c.ccc_id
from mmm m
left join ppp p using (main_id)
left join ccc c using (main_id)
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for. I read that cross join gives "all rows in both tables," then saw that it didn't do what I wanted and that threw me off. I also assumed that left join would not include rows from the right table, so I got confused further. I am still struggling a little to learn the differences between the join types, so thank you for pointing me in the right direction here!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `CASE` statements to replace values with `NULL` under certain conditions, and use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    mmm.main_id,
    CASE
        WHEN mmm.main_id = ppp.main_id THEN
            ppp.ppp_id
        ELSE
            NULL
    END AS ppp_id,
    CASE
        WHEN mmm.main_id = ccc.main_id THEN
            ccc.ccc_id
        ELSE
            NULL
    END AS ccc_id
FROM
    mmm,
    ppp,
    ccc
WHERE
    mmm.main_id = ppp.main_id OR
    mmm.main_id = ccc.main_id
;
```